# python tkinter transparency inherited by all the widgets under root

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a root window which is transparent. I also have a label which is a child of the root window. I notice that the label is also equally transparent as the root. Below is the code I am using:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

def exit(event):
    root.destroy()

class TestApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.label = tk.Label(self.parent, font=("Arial", 18, 'bold'),
                        width=30, fg="red")
        self.label.configure(text="Test message")
        self.label.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testApp = TestApp(root)

    root.bind("<Key>", exit)
    root.geometry("%sx%s" % (screen_width, screen_height))
    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.lower()
    root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
    root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
    root.mainloop()
```

If the value of alpha is 0.3 (in the line root.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)), then the text is visible on the screen, but if it is 0.0, then the text is not visible on the screen. Just want to know how it is possible to set the transparency for root to 0.0, and have the label text visible on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor","white")
```

This will make the color that you give transparent.
If you want to make `root` background transparent,you can use `root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", root['bg'])`.And then,you needn't to set
`root.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)`

Your code should be:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

def exit(event):
    root.destroy()

class TestApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.label = tk.Label(self.parent, font=("Arial", 18, 'bold'),
                        width=30, fg="red")
        self.label.configure(text="Test message")
        self.label.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testApp = TestApp(root)

    root.bind("<Key>", exit)
    root.geometry("%sx%s" % (screen_width, screen_height))
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.lower()
    root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
    root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", root['bg'])
    root.mainloop()
```